# jQuery mouseenter/leave doesn't work with li:nth-child():before

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, pseudo-element

In the below code, I try to display content: *text* with jquery.

If I delete `:before` it works!  Why doesn't jQuery allow that while javascript do that.

[This post (7 years ago)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)
talks about my problem, but it works around the problem without giving a simple solution.

Today there is no simple solution to target `:before`?

thanks for your help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").mouseenter(function() {
    $("li:nth-child(2):before").show();
  });
  $("div").mouseleave(function() {
    $("li:nth-child(2):before").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  display: none;
}

li:before {
  content: 'Show me';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>This is a paragraph.</li>
  <li>This is a second paragraph.</li>
</ul>

<div style="width:30px; height:30px; background:black;cursor:pointer;position:absolute; top:50px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pseudo-element's visibility depends on the visibility (i.e. `display` status) of its main element, the `li:nth-child(2)`. So you have to add an according line in your jQuery functions to also show/hide the main element:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").mouseenter(function(){
        $("li:nth-child(2)").show();
        $("li:nth-child(2):before").show();
    });
    $("div").mouseleave(function(){
        $("li:nth-child(2)").hide();
        $("li:nth-child(2):before").hide();
    });
});
```

```css
li{display:none;}
li:before{content:'Show me';}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li>This is a paragraph.</li>
<li>This is a second paragraph.</li>
</ul>

<div style="width:30px; height:30px; background:black;cursor:pointer;position:absolute; top:50px;"></div>


</body>
</html>
```